# Selection.Cells - SetWidth of merged cell

Tags: vba, ms-word, cell

I use the code bellow to add table to my Word document.

```
 With ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 2, 6)
      .Cell(1, 5).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(2, 6)
      .Cell(1, 3).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(1, 4)
      .Cell(1, 1).Merge MergeTo:=.Cell(2, 2)
      .Borders.Enable = True
      
      **Selection.Cells(1).SetWidth ColumnWidth:=104, RulerStyle:= _
        wdAdjustFirstColumn**
        
   End With
```

Inside the code, a select the first cell, so that i could make it small.

My question is: How can i access others cells that are mixed?
I got errors trying to do it.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't set the **column** widths *before* merging the cells?

Comment: Once you merge cells horizontally in a table you lose the ability to address the table's columns. Once you merge cells vertically you lose the ability to access individual rows. Therefore, if you can't avoid merging, do it last, and only when you don't need to count columns or rows (as the case may be) any more. You can still move from cell to cell counting paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply **macropod** and **Variatus**.

Comment: **Variatus**... how i would do the resizing of the columns before mergin it?

Answer (score 0):

Once cells are merged you can't count them directly as Table Row and Column, but you work within the range of a Row and access individual Cells (merged or not) within the range. Here is an example:

```
Sub CountRangeCells()
    Dim doc As Word.Document, tbl As Word.Table
    Dim rng As Word.Range, t As Long, r As Long, C As Long
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    For t = 1 To doc.Tables.Count
        Set tbl = doc.Tables(t)
        For r = 1 To tbl.rows.Count
            Set rng = tbl.rows(r).Range
            For C = 1 To rng.Cells.Count
                Debug.Print t, r, C, rng.Cells(C).Width
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```